# How to distinguish between date, month and year in the string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I have a question: How to use "strip" function to slice a date like "24.02.1999"?
The output should be like this '24', '02', '1999'.

Can you help to solve this?

Comment: The `strip` function has nothing to do with this. Did you mean `split`?

Comment: How do you think you can solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46937126/edit) to include more information.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: 'code' date = input("Enter date: ")
x()=date.split(".")
print(x()) 'code'

Comment: This is the code and I get a arror: SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strip` is used to remove the characters. What you meant is `split`. For your code,

```
date = input('Enter date in the format (DD.MM.YY) : ')
dd, mm, yyyy = date.strip().split('.')
print('day = ',dd)
print('month = ',mm)
print('year = ',yyyy)
```

Output:

```
Enter date in the format (DD.MM.YY) : 24.02.1999
day =  24
month =  02
year =  1999
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
    >>> stri="24.02.1999"
    >>> stri.split('.')
    ['24', '02', '1999']
    >>>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr Lade!

Comment: Welcome. If that is the answer , plz mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `split()` not `strip()`.

`strip()` is used to remove the specified characters from a string.

`split()` is used to split the string to list based on the value provided.

```
date = str(input()) # reading input date in dd.mm.yyyy format
splitted_date = date.split('.') # splitting date 

day = splitted_date[0] # storing day
month = splitted_date[1] # storing month
year = splitted_date[2] # storing year

# Display the values
print('Date : ',date)
print('Month : ',month)
print('Year : ',year)
```

You can split date given in `DD.MM.YYYY` format like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
 date="24.02.1999"
 [dd,mm,yyyy] = date.split('.')
 output=(("'%s','%s','%s'") %(dd,mm,yyyy))
 print(output)
```

alternate way

```
 date="24.02.1999"
 dd=date[0:2]
 mm=date[3:5]
 yyyy=date[6:10]
 newdate=(("'%s','%s','%s'") %(dd,mm,yyyy))
 print(newdate)
```

one more alternate way

```
from datetime import datetime

date="24.02.1999"
date=datetime.strptime(date, '%d.%m.%Y')
date=(("'%s','%s','%s'") %(date.day,date.month,date.year))
print(date)
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting the string, you should be using [**`datetime.strptime(..)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert the string to the [datetime object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) like:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> my_date_str = "24.02.1999"
>>> my_date = datetime.strptime(my_date_str, '%d.%m.%Y')
```

Then you can access the values you desire as:

```
>>> my_date.day  # For date
24
>>> my_date.month  # For month
2
>>> my_date.year  # For year
1999
```